# SMO 2014 with SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am doing an application that requires SQL Feature Pack against SQL Server versions 2014 and 2016.
Can I continue to use SMO 2014 instead of 2016 ?
Can someone clarify why it works.
Thanks

Comment: [SMO supports SQL Server 2005 and later versions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: From my experience, if you want to run against SQL Server 2014 and 2016, you **must use** SMO for SQL Server 2016. I had a client who had the situation just like you describe - using an "older" SMO against a newer SQL Server instance, and we ran into plenty of sometimes obvious, sometimes obscure errors when doing so. Not recommended.